# Android studio 3.4 taking too much time to build the project

Tags: android-studio

After updating the android studio to android 3.4 it's taking too much time to build the project before that it's taking only a few minutes but now it's taking too much time 
[image]

**EDIT**

even after one hour it keeps building the project.

Comment: Have you tried **invalidate cache and restart** ?

Comment: yes, I did, clean build, removing .build nothing helpful

Comment: @VirendraVarma Please update your solution. It will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi @mnp343, I install the old version, sorry I didn't have any solution

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your response. I did the same.

Comment: Go to your project Directory delete build directory delete .gradle directory delete .idea directory and you see some unseen un-familiar files name like java_pid920.hprof delete all of them and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

@VirendraVarma Your solution worked for me, Appreciate it,  but just to make it clear for everyone else.

1. Close the current Android Studio project

2. Go to your project's directory and delete all build, .gradle, .idea folders. Also any unfamiliar files as stated by Varma.

3. Now at the Android Studio welcome screen, click on open an existing Android Studio project and the rest should be quite straightforward.